# Find the greatest number such that when 76151 and 226 are divided by it, the remainders are all alike?

Tags: number-theory

Find the greatest number such that when 76151 and 226 are divided by it, the remainders are all alike?

I have no idea how to approach such problem, so I can't even give it a try.num

Answer (score 2):

Let denote this number by $n$ and the remainder by $r$ so we have

$$r=76151-np=226-nq\implies n|(76151-226)\land( n\le226)$$
so we find $n=25$.

Comment: I am not aware of this - n|(76151−226)∧(n≤226) and how you solved it to get n= 25? where is (p-q) term?

Comment: We have $n(p-q)=76151-226$ which means that $n$ divides this number. The greatest number that divide $75925$ and less or equal $226$ is $25$

Comment: We have to find the value of n, so n = 75925/(p-q). But your explanation is still confusing to me. Why we will concentrate on the number that divides 759525

Comment: The numbers that divide 75925 are 1;  5; 25 ;3037;15185;75925 so $n$ is one of them. What we choose as value for $n$? is there other information on $n$?

Comment: Thanks...I now got it. But how will I know 75925 are divisible by which numbers, like you calculated and mentioned?

Comment: We decompose 75925 on its primary decomposition: we divide it first by 5 we find 15185 so we divide it by 5 we find 3037 which's a prime.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. But another answer gave another answer; that is 75. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, take n=76151-226= 75925.

When you divide 76151 by n, you obtain 1 and have a remainder of 226.

When you divide 226 by n, you obtain 0 and have a remainder of 226.

You can't have any greater number, because with any greater number $m>n$, you will obtain a remainder less than 226 for $76151/n$ if $n\le 76151$ or a remainder equals to 76151 otherwise. So $n$ is the greatest number.

Comment: Although your answer is correct in the general case but I understand implicitly from the question that $n$ is  less than 226.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane If it's not explicitly written, you can't make such a strong hypothesis ! If the OP forgot about it, it's his responsibility.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane in the question it was not mentioned. but I guess it's understandable.

Comment: Or you both make a mistake by making a wrong hypothesis...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If the number is $n$, you have $76151=an+b, 226=cn+b$  How can you get rid of $b$?

Comment: I have already tried this way, and it comes down to (a-c)n = 75925. Then the question comes how to get rid of a and c? This question provides no further info.

Comment: Now you know $n$ is a factor of $75925$. There aren't too many of those.